# Extract symbolic coefficient

Tags: matlab

I have an symbolic equation like

```
syms q
syms M N O
A=M*q^2+N*q+O
```

now I wanna to extract 'M' from above equation
I've done following works

```
coeffs(A,q)*[0;0;1]
```

and the answer is

```
ans=
M
```

so I wanna know is there any better way to extract M directly from the equation?
Thanks all.

Comment: I'd do it that way too